# Xquery delete leaves empty lines in xml document - how to remove them? (eXist-db)

Tags: xquery, exist-db

In XQuery 3.1 (eXist 4.7) I have an operation that deletes nodes from a stored XML document at `/db/apps/myapp/data/list_bibliography.xml` that looks like this:

```
<listBibl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="bibliography">
    <tei:biblStruct xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" type="book" xml:id="Z-BF2WLW8Y">
        <tei:monogr>
            <tei:title level="m">footitle1</tei:title>
            <tei:author>
                <tei:name>author name</tei:name>
            </tei:author>
            <tei:imprint>
                <tei:publisher>some city</tei:publisher>
                <tei:date>2019</tei:date>
            </tei:imprint>
        </tei:monogr>
    </tei:biblStruct>
    <tei:biblStruct xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" type="book" xml:id="Z-4KF7YNP3">
        <tei:monogr>
            <tei:title level="m">footitle2</tei:title>
            <tei:author>
                <tei:name>author name</tei:name>
            </tei:author>
            <tei:imprint>
                <tei:publisher>some other city</tei:publisher>
                <tei:date>2018</tei:date>
            </tei:imprint>
        </tei:monogr>
    </tei:biblStruct>
</listBibl>
```

The following function:

```
declare local:delete-bibl()
{
   let $bibdoc := doc("/db/apps/myapp/data/list_bibliography.xml")
   for $bib in $bibdoc//tei:biblStruct[@xml:id = "Z-BF2WLW8Y"]
   return update delete $bib
};
```

leaves the file with whitespace like this:

```
<listBibl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="bibliography">












    <tei:biblStruct xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" type="book" xml:id="Z-4KF7YNP3">
        <tei:monogr>
            <tei:title level="m">footitle2</tei:title>
            <tei:author>
                <tei:name>author name</tei:name>
            </tei:author>
            <tei:imprint>
                <tei:publisher>some other city</tei:publisher>
                <tei:date>2018</tei:date>
            </tei:imprint>
        </tei:monogr>
    </tei:biblStruct>
</listBibl>
```

Is there some sort of configuration or function that can collapse the white space left by `delete`?

I tried using instead `return update replace $bib with ""` but that throws errors as the replacement must be a node.

Many thanks.

Comment: I think this leftover whitespace could be considered a bug. Would you consider filing this as a bug report to https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/new? The sample data and query here would be sufficient to demonstrate it here. Nothing in the docs suggests that users should expect whitespace to be left in place of deleted nodes.

Comment: @joewiz added to github

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to file the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no configuration option for collapsing the whitespace left by eXist's XQuery Update `delete` operations.

To work around the error you received when replacing `$bib` with an empty string, instead replace it with a text node:

```
update replace $bib with text { "" }
```